# GWan Hello.c error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, g-wan

I'm trying out Gwan, got it running in virtualbox (wmware seems too slow) on ubuntu on  another machine. Installed and ran sudo ./gwan, it complained about java, ruby, php etc, I figured it's ok as I wanted to test the C part only.

So I can ping fine, but when I run hello world, I get error time out. Gwan process is running fine 4.3.14. No modification, straight out of install.

```
http://192.168.0.127:8080/?hello.c
```

Comment: Do you have GCC installed ?

Comment: G-WAN did not *"complain about java, ruby, php etc"* it just informed you that to use the scripts in those languages you had to install the corresponding runtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running out of the box, you are using port 8080 at address 0.0.0.0 which means that GWAN is listening at all addresses.

So if you are running the browser inside the virtualbox machine why don't you try 127.0.0.1:8080/?hello.c

If you are running the browser outside the virtualbox machine, then it could be a network configuration problem.

Check out the FAQs of http://www.gwan.com/faq they give great information regarding installation and general problems.

Comment: ah.. got it working. I set the networking to nat instead of bridge, so it was a networking setup issue. Thanks.